# How to replace images in 2nd page when an anchor from 1st page was clicked ? in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 two pages in my website. Page 1 contains few images and page 2 containers another few images. When I click on a particular image in page 1 I want to change all images in page 2.
I am able to redirect to the page 2 but couldn't make changes affect.Please help.

--Page 1 --

```
<div class="container collections-cont">
<a href="#"><img src="images/collections/b.jpeg" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/collections/c.jpeg" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/collections/d.jpeg" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/collections/e.jpeg" /></a>
</div>
```

--Page 2 --

```
   <div class="vertical-suba">
      <img src="../images/collections/a.jpeg">
      <img src="../images/collections/b.jpeg">
      <img src="../images/collections/c.jpeg">
      <img src="../images/collections/d.jpeg">
      <img src="../images/collections/e.jpeg">
    </div>
```

-- JavaScript --

```
let colImgRed=document.querySelectorAll(".collections-cont a");
let vertImg=document.querySelectorAll(".vertical-suba img");
let newProImg=["images/collections/f.jpeg","images/collections/g.jpeg","images/collections/h.jpeg","images/collections/i.jpeg","images/collections/j.jpeg",]
let i;

colImgRed[0].onclick=function(){
  
  for(i=0;i<vertImg.length;i++){
    vertImg[i].src=newProImg[i];
  }
  
  location.href="html/product.html";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, what i would do is making each anchor have a specific fragment (#), like this

```
<div class="container collections-cont">
<a href="#b"><img src="images/collections/b.jpeg" /></a>
<a href="#c"><img src="images/collections/c.jpeg" /></a>
<a href="#d"><img src="images/collections/d.jpeg" /></a>
<a href="#e"><img src="images/collections/e.jpeg" /></a>
</div>
```

And then in your javascript for page 2, checking the fragment and updating your images accordingly

```
let vertImg = document.querySelectorAll(".vertical-suba img");
let newProImg=["images/collections/f.jpeg","images/collections/g.jpeg","images/collections/h.jpeg","images/collections/i.jpeg","images/collections/j.jpeg",]

switch (location.hash) {
  case "#a":
  for(let i=0;i<vertImg.length;i++){
    vertImg[i].src=newProImg[i];
  }
  break;
}
```

What i did here is matching the [fragment](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp) in a [switch](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) statement
`case "#a":` checks if the fragment matches "#a", and if so it changes the images to the new images

Comment: Not working! How can we expect it to work? There is not even a link to redirect another page.

Comment: Can you please give us some more code or info about your project? Otherwise i cannot help you